# Can I use Different Codeigniter Installation for a Single Project?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and planning to build an Application using Codeigniter MVC. It is having 3 modules, ie User, companies and Admin section. Is there any disadvantages if I use two codeigniter installations. Ie One for admin section and all other parts on another installation?

Comment: [HMVC](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/) is made exactly for that and I would never suggest using multiple installations for a single app.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that, try this http://cibonfire.com/

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You should choose the latest version and code project to that, because what happens when you have to upgrade for updates, bug fixes, etc and suddenly you have two installations at two different versions that can potentially break. Maintaining such a system would be be a nightmare.

Comment: How I handle it is by separating the code within one application, by adding an `Admin` folder into the controllers, models, and views folders. It's a lot easier to manage than running two separate applications.

Answer (score -1):

I use multiple CI instances in some of our products but they're entirely different applications which only overlap on a few small areas like authentication.

There are more than a few gotchas using multiple instances together (auth/sessions being the big one) and I wouldn't do it unless you really need to. If you only want some members to access some pages, that's easy enough to do in CI - and you'll probably have a lot of code reuse. If you split into 2 CI instances, you need to maintain 2 similar but different code bases - a maintenance pain. The more overlap there is, the greater the duplication of effort.